# why my scheme code parenthesis have no colors even I've installed vscode-scheme extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, scheme

parenthesis in schme has no colors. I've installed vscode scheme extension.

vscode-scheme example code
[image]

my code in vscode:
[image]

Comment: I switched to sublime text, there are some plugins can meet my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket Pair Colorizer

this vscode extension feed my needs